# subset on id's and date

Tags: r, date, subset, mean

I have a data set that consists of years of data for various individuals (id)

I want to look at each year and find the average number of score entries for individuals in that year.

```
id year score
2  2011  1
2  2011  3
2  2012  4
3  2008  4
54 2011  3
45 2011  3
45 2011  3
```

if i wanted to subset for 2011 then the following would be returned

```
    id year score
    2  2011  1
    2  2011  3
    54 2011  3
    45 2011  3
    45 2011  3
```

and the average would simply be frequency of scores in 2011 (5) / number of different id's (3) = 5/3=1.666

how can i do this in code for a data set that is 1000's of rows long?

Comment: So you just want to subset your data where year==2011? What code have you tried? What problem are you having exactly? Subseting data.frames is a pretty basic R operation. Have you read the [introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Use `length(score) / length(unique(id))` with your choice of plyr, dplyr, data.table. There are millions of questions like these if you look around.

Comment: Thanks! I had the subset part covered it was just the length(unique(id)) that I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R functions to do this:

```
within(dat[idx <- dat$year == 2011, ], average <- length(unique(id)) / sum(idx))
#   id year score average
# 1  2 2011     1     0.6
# 2  2 2011     3     0.6
# 5 54 2011     3     0.6
# 6 45 2011     3     0.6
# 7 45 2011     3     0.6
```